# Are questions regarding historical tournament results of MTG decks on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, magic-the-gathering, questions, specific-question

There is a question I've been meaning to ask about the history of tournament results of certain *Magic: The Gathering* decks during a particular standard season, but I am not completely sure whether the BCG Stack Exchange is the right place to ask it.

The question would be along the lines of:

> Did [archetype] decks get any significant standard tournament results during the standard of [block] and [block]?

Would that be on-topic for this site?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, regardless of the deck

As murgatroid says:

> A rule about whether questions are on topic needs to depend on the topic itself, not on external information about the specific subject.

Let the votes decide if a particular question is an issue, and we can address any flooding if questions if it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

My view: yes, *but only for decks which are in some way already notable*. To take some recent examples, asking about [Omnath Adventures](https://strategy.channelfireball.com/all-strategy/mtg/channelmagic-news/austin-bursavich-wins-the-2020-season-grand-finals/) in Zendikar Rising standard would be on-topic as the deck was very successful, so much so [its namesake card was very rapidly banned](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/news/october-12-2020-banned-and-restricted-announcement). On the other hand, asking about Mono-Black Aggro in Zendikar Rising standard, a deck which saw effectively no high-level play, would not be on-topic as that would just open the floodgates to an huge number of questions (every deck archetype in every timeframe), most of which would not add any value over an MtG database site.

Comment: I understand your concerns about opening the floodgates, but I wonder two things. 1) What threshold do you set for a deck to be considered successful and 2) if you already know a deck is successful enough to meet the threshold why wouldn't you know enough to not ask the question?

Comment: I'm not sure what my own answer to this question would be, but this is not the right line to draw. A rule about whether questions are on topic needs to depend on the topic itself, not on external information about the specific subject. Plus, my experience has been that it's never really worth worrying about "opening the floodgates". If we were going to have a problem like that, we would already have that problem, because most people don't put this kind of work into checking whether their question is on topic before asking it.